# How to detect other hosts on LAN messenger using a single UDP port?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, lan, messenger

As stated in the [IP Messenger Help](http://ipmsg.org/ipmsghlp_eng.htm) , it uses a UDP Port 2425 to detect other hosts. How does it actually achieves it with a single port??

How do I proceed to achieve this, like say create a socket, then broadcast and all the steps.

Any Ideas and Help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Any particular reason to not use mDNS?

Comment: Great!!! suits my needs. Any tutorials :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create datagram socket()
2. bind() the port
3. prepare packet
4. sendto() UDP packet to the broadcast (mulicast) address
5. recvfrom() as many answer as you want

Comment: i'm not clear about how to prepare a packet to send..I mean should it be a simple string or anything like that which I would broadcast.

Comment: Do you want to write program capable with referred ip messenger?

Comment: Yes I want it to be capable with ip messenger

Comment: So you should find protocol specefication or reverse engneer it.